# Обновление старой версии PHP на debian

Tags: php, debian

Хочу обновить текущую версию php до последней в ветке 5.4 (сейчас это 5.4.40).
Как проделать эту операцию не поломав PHP и модули?

```
# php -v
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u9 (cli) (built: Apr 18 2014 14:34:31)

# dpkg -l | grep php
ii  php5-cli                        5.4.4-14+deb7u9               
ii  php5-common                     5.4.4-14+deb7u9               
ii  php5-curl                       5.4.4-14+deb7u9               
ii  php5-fpm                        5.4.4-14+deb7u9               
ii  php5-gd                         5.4.4-14+deb7u9               
ii  php5-imagick                    3.1.0~rc1-1+b2                
ii  php5-mcrypt                     5.4.4-14+deb7u9               
ii  php5-mysql                      5.4.4-14+deb7u9               
ii  php5-xcache                     2.0.0-4                       
ii  php5-xmlrpc                     5.4.4-14+deb7u9
```

Comment: Последняя версия 5.6

Comment: add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

До 5.6:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
apt-get update;
apt-get install --only-upgrade php5-fpm php5-gd php5-curl ...
```

До 5.4.40:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
apt-get update;
apt-get install --only-upgrade php5-fpm php5-gd php5-curl ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Обнови все пакеты:

```
apt-get update; apt-get upgrade;
```

Если только PHP:

```
apt-get update; apt-get install php5;
```